# Compass bearings on excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

Would like some help creating an excel formula:

Compass bearings are from 0 to 359. I have attached a picture of how it looks like here:

[image: Compass bearing]

Basically, I am looking for a solution for when I input 2 columns of compass bearings into excel, it will give me left or right. Let me give an example:

From 120 to 165, output should be "right", 120 to 105 should be "left".

From 345 to 15, output should be "right" instead of "left". Similarly, from 15 to 345, the output should be "left" instead of "right".

I am pretty new at excel, so I apologize in advance if there is an easy solution to this. Nevertheless, any help here will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like homework?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it, that way we can help you find the error. Like this, it is much more work for us to do in order to help you.

Comment: You should provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Let's go through the solution step by step.

First of all, remember that in addition to the "right" and "left" you mentioned, two more options can occur: "keep moving forward" if the old and new values of compass bearings are the same, and "go back" if the difference between them is exactly 180 degrees.

Now let's rotate the compass card so that the old azimuth is aligned with 0, with the direction due north. The new azimuth will also rotate by that angle. While the new azimuth is on the right, there are no problems, but what if it turns out to be to the left of zero? This negative value will mess up all calculations. Let's bring this value to the correct one, in the range from 0 to 359 degrees. It's not difficult - add 360 (or 720, or 1080) and take the remainder of the division by 360. Thus, -15 will turn into the correct 345 degrees.

Now let's subtract half of the circle, 180 degrees, from this value and look at the sign of the result: in the case of a negative value, you should turn to the right, in the case of a positive one, to the left, and in the case of zero, go back. The sign will let us know the SIGN() function - it returns -1, 0 or 1. To use this value in the CHOOSE() function, you need to change these values ​​​​to 1, 2 and 3. Therefore, just add 2. Thus, your task is solved using a formula like as

```
=IF(A1=B1;"Steady! (forward)";CHOOSE(SIGN(MOD(B1-A1+720;360)-180)+2;"Starboard! (right)";"Full reverse! (back)";"Port! (left)"))
```